# Store views file in filesystem with thymeleaf and spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm configuring thymealeaf as a template engine in my spring mvc application. Here I copy my configuration that is working correctly:

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine"
      class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>


<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

with this configuration the view files are stored in /WEB-INF/pages/ directory in my project folder, but I would like to store the *.html view files in my filesystem for example in my user folder in my mac, so the template resolver should resolve at runtime the view. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

I use this for development time:

```
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.FileTemplateResolver">
   <property name="prefix" value="/whatever/file/path/directory"/>
   <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
   <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5"/>
   <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Like this the templates are resolved on ever page refresh and not only with the deployment of the war. Gives me more speed in the development.

Comment: It's probably worth emphasizing that you have to use ```FileTemplateResolver``` for this to work.